# Differenze di uso tra "ombrello", "ombrella" e "ombrellone"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Non capisco bene quali siano le differenze di uso tra questi vocaboli: "ombrello", "ombrella" e "ombrellone". Me le potreste spiegare? Ad esempio, qual è il termine comunemente usato per indicare quello che si usa per ripararsi dal sole in spiaggia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ombrello" è per la pioggia, o parasole, ma in generale portatile;

"Ombrellone" è quello che ripara dal sole, fisso o poco mobile e per più persone ([o un tavolo in giardino](http://img.orchidee.biz/immagini/003/Ombrelloni-da-esterno_m.jpg));

"Ombrella" è secondo [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ombrella) una infiorescenza, che ha in comune con gli altri due l'idea del gambo che si apre in steli multipli. Credo che sia usata anche come sinonimo di "ombrello", ma in regionalismi e sicuramente molto poco, come dimostra anche [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ombrello%2C+ombrella&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Combrello%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Combrella%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: "Ombrella", per quanto orribile, si può sentire in Lombardia, nel contesto di un italiano fortemente influenzato dal dialetto. Compare anche in una [canzone di Jannacci e Renato Pozzetto](http://wikitesti.com/e_la_vita_la_vita/).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: E perché sarebbe "orribile"?

Comment: @Charo Innanzitutto intendo quando usato nel senso di "copertura contro la pioggia", non in quello suo proprio dell'infiorescenza. All'orecchio di un italiano suona sgrammaticato, e la sua origine dialettale (almeno per me) me lo fa associare inconsciamente a un livello culturale basso. Detto questo, in sé la parola non ha nulla di strano; potrebbe esistere un mondo parallelo in cui "ombrello" è femminile e non ci sarebbe nulla di sconvolgente.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni :    Io, che abito a Barcellona, nella mia lingua dico "el cotxe" (vuol dire automobile, macchina), ma nel catalano del Rossiglione si dice ["la vutura"](http://issuu.com/amicsmontella/docs/fd32/13), che ha una chiara influenza del francese. Seguendo il tuo ragionamento, posso pensare che quelli che parlano il catalano del Rossiglione sono di un livello culturale più basso. O forse sono io ad avere un livello culturale più basso perché il vocabolo "cotxe" proviene dal castigliano "coche".

Comment: Nel catalano dell'Alghero però dicono ["automòbil"](http://www.algueres.net/vocabols/2495/automobil.aspx): quelli sì che hanno un livello culturale alto!  ;)

Comment: @Charo Dal mio punto di vista usare "ombrella" è come se tu dicessi "la cotxe" o "el vutura" perché confondi i generi nelle due lingue. Inoltre immagino che in Spagna ci sia un approccio verso le lingue locali molto diverso; in Italia (o almeno nel Nord), per molti anni, il dialetto è stato visto solo come la lingua del popolo meno istruito che non frequentava scuole e luoghi culturali, quindi c'è una sorta di stigma. In tempi più recenti si sta cercando di recuperare la cultura locale e dialettale, ma per lungo tempo c'è stata questa connotazione.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Anche in Spagna, fino a poco tempo fa, c'era questa concezione, e non solo questo: il catalano e le altre lingue "locali" erano proibite durante la dittatura di Franco.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Inoltre, non mi sembra tanto strano cambiare il genere delle parole a seconda delle regioni: io dico "el tomàquet", ma in alcune regioni ("comarques") del Sud della Catalogna dicono "la tomaca" o "la tomata".

Comment: @Charo: Federico ha perfettamente ragione. Chiamare l'ombrello "l'ombrella", come in altri casi di genere cambiato ("le 80 euro", per rifarsi a un'altra domanda), é alle orecchie di un parlante nativo segno di un individuo del Nord di bassa cultura e influenzato da forme dialettali e non é corretto in Italiano standard. Fonte: parlante nativo :) Volendo si potrebbe fare un lungo discorso sul fatto che esistono regionalismi di maggiore e minor prestigio, tra i primi dei quali ci sono ad esempio quelli del centro Italia, probabilmente anche grazie alla TV, ma esula dall'argomento.

Comment: P.S.: *dittatura di Franco

Comment: @TobiaTesan: Grazie, l'ho corretto.